# Dealing with security in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm not sure that this qualifies as an actual question but the react-redux repo is for bugs, not open-ended questions such as this.

I'm about to adopt react-redux for a new project where some data needs to be stored in state. The data - in this case an Id - will be used to get related information for the current user.

For example the state will store `campaignId:1` and will be changed on the frontend by the user. When changed, the return result will be the details for the selected campaign (which only belongs to the currently logged in user).

My questions are:

- Is this the correct way to handle related data?
- Are there security implications around storing an Id in this manner? Can it be "hacked"?

Comment: Your backend server side code should handle the security. If a user requests a campaign that doesn't belong to them, you should not return the data, instead return something like 404 Not Found.

Comment: Yep, sure I get this - but still, is this the correct way to handle the relation on the front-end?

Comment: Hard to say without more details, but I don't see anything wrong with what you've described so far.